# Obtaining the default section spacing into the \titlespacing* parameters

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'm using the `book` class.

I want to modify the spacing before and after my sections using the `\titlespacing*` command.

However, before I do that, I want to let its parameters be such that they reproduce exactly what they were by default. This way, I can have the default “baseline-setting” on which I can base my modifications upon. (I'm especially interested in knowing how the default settings are for the stretching/shrinking before and after the section title.)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It can be found in the [`titlesec` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
```

Comment: And in the standard classes (book.cls, for exampe) you find `\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`. The fourth anf fifth arguments give the spacing after and before.