# How to reduce space between heading (e.g. "List of figures") and contents in thesis

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

I have trouble reducing the space between the the title like LIST OF FIGURES, TABLE OF CONTENTS, etc., and the list body body in my thesis. I had the same problems with chapter headings, which I fixed by using `\vskip -2.5` in each chapter. However, since the table of contents etc. are fixed by document class itself (my guess), I am not able to do this. I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem -- among other things, it will show which document class you use.

Comment: You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228); that would tell which class you're using. In the `book` class, `\listoffigures` is defined to generate the list of figures after a `\chapter*` command. Therefore, instead of hardcoding `\vskip ...` after each chapter, you'd be better off changing the spacing of all chapter headings using the `\titlespacing` command from the `titlesec` package. Have a look [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48753/obtaining-the-default-section-spacing-into-the-titlespacing-parameters) for more details.

Comment: No MWE: sorry but this is 'unclear'