# LaTeX vertical spacing after numbered paragraphs

Tags: spacing, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I'm relatively new to this forum and LaTeX in general, so please excuse me if I'm duplicating a question, but I can't find a satisfying solution to my problem. I have introduced numbered paragraphs by extending the secnumdepth to 4. Now, I would like to have the same appearance as with the subsubsection titles and the associated text for these numbered paragraphs. Therefore, I have added a line break after the paragraph title and indentation to the first line of text (I'm using `\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}`), but I would also like to add the same vertical spacing between the title and the associated text as done with `\subsubsection`. I tried using `\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}` (= default titlespacing settings for subsubsections, found here: [Obtaining the default section spacing into the \titlespacing* parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48753/obtaining-the-default-section-spacing-into-the-titlespacing-parameters)), but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure whether this is relevant, but I'm using the `scrreprt` class. Can anyone help me, please? Here is my code including the entire preamble in case that something interferes with anything else:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{caption}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.)}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter title}

    Sample text

    \section{Section title}

    Sample text

    \subsection{Subsection title}

    Sample text

    \subsubsection{Subsubsection title}

    Sample text

    \paragraph{Paragraph title}

    \ \\
    \indent Sample text

    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier than you might think, without loading any package.

[image: frownKomaSpacingParagraph]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,
egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles% The name of this option might change in the future
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{caption}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.)}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
  beforeskip=3.25explus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,%
]{paragraph}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Walter Wombat}

He lives in Australia.

\section{Carl Capybara}

He lives in South America.

\subsection{Milli Mara}

She lives in Patagonia

\subsubsection{Brigitte Beaver}

She lives in Europe.

\paragraph{Nadja Nasenb\"ar}

Maybe she lives in M\"onchengladbach.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about adding a `\vspace{10pt}` between your paragraph title and the text?
You could redefine the paragraph command to implement it in your whole document:

```
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{{#1}\mbox{}\vspace{10pt}}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I thought I had tried adding \vspace at every possible position between the title and the text, but I just realised that I obviously missed one because now, I simply inserted \vspace{12pt} between "\ " and "\\" (see above code) and it works perfectly! Sorry for bothering you guys unnecessarily and thank you for your suggestion anyways, LeCoco! Just for sake of completeness: I simply copied your suggestion into my document and it caused the paragraph title to lose both its numbering and its bold font, no idea why, maybe someone can explain?

Comment: i'm not a user of the `koma` classes, but unless `scrreport` is very much different from other classes, adding explicit vertical space between the heading and the text permits the heading to be left alone at the bottom of a page, which is undesirable.  the redefinition of `\paragraph` in the answer, on the other hand, removes all formatting of the heading except for placing it on a separate line.

Comment: This redefinition of `\paragraph` manages to lose all of the desirable properties of the macro, including automatic numbering, bold-facing of  the argument, non-indentation, space *above* the paragraph-level header. In short, don't employ this redefinition.